# Is it possible to arrange a trial of chatter plus?

Tags: chatter, licenses

I've read about Salesforce Chatter Plus and it seems to fit requirements for our select range of users, however I would like to try it out before I sign up to licenses, is it possible to get a trial? Do I need to contact our Salesforce sales rep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can usually get your AE (Account Executive) to give you a 30 day license for a couple of users. Just contact your AE.